# Restful web service sending in URL and Arabic Latters

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restful-url

I create RESTful web service in Netbeans that take an Arabic text in the URL and then send back string also in Arabic letters.

this is a sample, same as I do

```
  @GET
    @Path("/getString/{text}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getString( @PathParam("text") String text ) {
       return text ;}
```

and when I use this: `/getString/السلام`

it returns Symbols. What should I do? Is there a need for encoding and how can i do it?

Comment: Try `@Produces( "text/plain; charset=utf-8" )`

Comment: not work :( .. is there other sol? @RealSkeptic

Comment: Not without seeing how exactly you are outputting the data.